# Распознать текст на пачке скриншотов

Tags: c++, распознавание-образов, распознавание-символов

Есть игра. Персонаж игры произносит много разных реплик (~400 штук). Они показваются текстом в левом верхнем углу экрана. Примеры:

[image]
[image]

Задача в игре поймать 250 разных реплик. Моя задача — вести учёт того, что уже поймано, количеству пойманных уникальных реплик. Играя, я делаю скриншоты. Часто делаю дубликаты, так как не помню, видел эту фразу или нет.

Т.е. на входе есть папка со скриншотами. Все скриншоты однотипные. Текст всегда в одном и том же месте (его можно выделить прямоугольником). Строчек может быть одна или две. Шрифт, цвет и прочее всегда одни и те же. Текст только на английском. Шрифт неизвестен. Фон не совсем чёрный, он немного прозрачный (сквозь него проступает что-то там из игры).

Я вижу два подхода:

**1. Вариант раз**
Удалить дубликаты. Пробежаться по всем скриншотам, выделить область текста, попарно сравнить. Как-то так.

**2. Вариант два**
Распознать все эти тексты, сохранить построчно в текстовик. Что делать с текстами — понятно.

**Вопрос**
Я не программист, последний раз кодил в университете, сейчас верстаю HTML. Тем не менее, задача мне не кажется сложной, плюс допустимы упрощения/упущения, лишь бы работало. Знаком с С/C++ из университетских курсов. "Hello, World!" написал, что делать дальше? :)

**Ответ**
Я так понимаю, что мне нужна библиотека для работы с изображениями. Наверное мне нужно посоветовать что-то подходящее под задачу. Чтобы мне было с чего начать гуглить.
В общем описать алгоритм, типа "сначала научись открывать файлы", "затем научись выделять нужную область", "после научись кропать картинку", "в итоге при помощи технологии Х научись выводить на экран текст". Ну и, конечно, что читать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Шрифт и его цвет всегда одинаковые?

Comment: Изучу. Всему свое время :)
Формат файла JPG. Вот оригинальный скриншот:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22619948/2015-01-17-044602.jpg
На рабочем компе стоит Windows 7.
Размер шрифта и цвет всегда одинаковые. Самом семейство неизвестно.

Comment: Все сильно зависит от Вашего желания. Я возможно сразу плюсами не бросался, если учитывать, что на них кодили давно-давно и знаете плохо.

Я бы брал питон - он тут в самый раз. К нему любую встроенную библиотеку обработки изображений, например PIL (встроенная) и написать самостоятельно простое распознания (за день можно управиться). А можно поискать библиотеки для OCR.

В целом, я для начала порекомендовал почитать статьи о том, как распознают каптчи. Эта задача очень близка к ней.

После получения текста можно применить алгоритмы нечеткого сравнения текста и находить дубликаты.

Comment: Про капчи хорошая мысль, спасибо. Питон? Питон я ни разу не видел в живую :) Но раз в самый раз пойду прочитаю про питон.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку OpenCV, самый простой вариант работы с изображениями, по-моему... За счет документации, примеров и поддержки нескольких языков.

Первым делом вырезаем прямоугольник с текстом.

Во-вторых, оставляем только те пиксели, которые белого цвета (насколько понял, фон меняется, а вот текст всегда белый).

В-третьих, уменьшить размер... Я бы предложит выкинуть пару раз каждый второй ряд и столбец из изображения, чтобы текст оставался читаем.

А дальше находим какую-нибудь хэш-функцию по изображению. И тогда надо будет сравнивать с набором чисел. Могу немного подробней расписать, если какой-то момент непонятен.

**UPD** Уточнения

1) OpenCV - один раз установил и потом проблем не будет.

2) "Удалить" фон нужно для того что бы все в итоге полученные картинки были строго одинаковые. Это будет гарантировать, то что вы не спутаете две картинки, даже если будете сравнивать попиксельно.

3) Первоочередным является уменьшить размер, что бы уменьшить коллизий при создании хэш-функции. Но и да, это должно очень повысить производительность. (Если два раза выкинуть каждую второю строку и 2 раза выкинуть каждый второй столбец, то это размер данных у вас уменьшиться примерно в 16 раз)

4) После обработки мы имеем черно-белые прямоугольники одинакового размера. Можно составить одну большую строку из 0 и 1. Можно конечно хранить такие строки и сравнивать их, но это тоже не слишком эффективно.

Наиболее эффективная хэш-функция для строк - это полиномиальный хэш. Вот [тут](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/string_hashes) хорошая статья с исходным кодом.

Comment: Спасибо. OpenCV сегодня пробовал. Полдня запускал пример из пакета установщика. Почти запустил :)

С прямоугольником все понятно.

Зачем отделять пиксели от фона? Фон там что-то типа черного с прозрачностью на 10%.

Зачем уменьшать размер? Чтобы работало быстрее при большом паке скриншотов?

Последний этап, про хэш-функции, буду, видимо, отдельно осмыслять, когда дойду.

Comment: И все-таки про коллизии при хэшировании (одинаковые значения хэш-функции для разных данных) лучше не забывать.

Возможно стоит поискать хэширование специфичное для изображений (images), а не символьных строк.

Comment: @avp, даже если задуматься о надежности, то если вычислять хэш по модулю порядка 2^64 (но конечно же простого), то вероятность наткнутся на коллизии мала. Можно еще уменьшить эту вероятность, считая одновременно два хэша по различным основаниям. Ну или вариант, если совпали хэши, то уже проверить сами изображения.

Comment: Тэкс, OpenCV установил, студию переустановил на 2013-ю. Запустил тестовый пример, учусь открывать, редактировать и пересохранять картинки. Пока двигаюсь в этом направлении.

Comment: @avp, я не знаю специфических, хэширование строк - как пример.

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, естественно, что если хэши совпали, то надо побайтно сравнивать.

Что же касается специфичных хэшей, то уверен, что они есть. Например, [Hash Functions for Near Duplicate Image Retrieval](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~cohen/mypapers/AuclairWACV09.pdf).

А возможно, тривиальные MD5 или SHA1 дадут хороший результат.

Answer (score 4):

Есть программа заточенная для создания ботов.
Кибор. Там есть функция распознавание текста. Можно текст распознавать прямо с экрана в играх. Генерируется готовый скрипт.
Даже можно без программирования такой скрипт создать. Для этого есть визуальный редактор кода.

[image: Настройка распознавания текста]

[image: Создание скрипта]

[image: Вставка скрипта для исполнения]

[image: Выполнение скрипта. Распознавание текста в указанной области]

Как я говорил можно создать программу которая будет сама распознавать текст в указанной области и делать с ним что надо. Записывать в файл, выдавать сообщение если нужный текст найден и т.д. Такой скрипт можно создать даже не зная программирования. В визуальном редакторе кода.
На этих видео показана работа и настройка распознавания текста

[работа и настройка распознавания текста](https://youtu.be/QVlrfQTlCzo)

На этом видео показан процесс создания готового бота для игры, где требуется распознавать текст. Бот создается без программирования

[Оптическое распознавание текста в Кибор Бот для Music Wars](https://youtu.be/lcnt9cbMuzw)

Сам Кибор [Кибор](http://kibor-bot.com/stat/programmed-autoclicker.php)